# Azure solution template manage visibility in same step

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I am writing a solution template where I have used 'Microsoft.Common.OptionsGroup' element. Based on its value I want to show/hide further fields in same step. But it is not happening as expected.

[image]

Here, I want that if I select 'No' then below 2 fields should be hidden.

I wrote as: "visible": "[equals(steps('createRepoServer'), 1)]"

But it does not work in same step and nothing happens if I select NO.
Does it not work in same step on Azure resource template?

Answer (score 0):

I could able to achieve this by using 'visible' option as:

> "visible":
>   "[steps('vmSettings').repositoryServerSettings.createRepoServer]"